# Use Jquery validation for validating dropdown selected item

Tags: jquery, validation, drop-down-menu, jquery-validate

I'm using Mvc web application, and I have a simple dropdown in my page. my dropdown has 3 items and I want to check selected item every time it changes.

Currently I'm writing a JavaScript function to handle dropdown "onchange" event. but as you know this event does not fire when you toggle dropdown items by keyboard.

how can I use jquery custom validation in this case ? I want every time my dropdown selected item changes, certain things happen like disabling a textbox.

Comment: Who said that onchange does not work when changing using keyboard? However, if your process does not apply real onchange event, use onfocus event for the list's options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

***Jquery code:***

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#dropdown').change(function() {  
    $('#selectedValue').html($(this).val()); // just to see what value did the user select
    if($(this).val()=='2'){// validating whether the user selected value 2 and disabling textbox
        $('#textbox').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

***Html code:***

```
<select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
<option id="select1" value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
<option id="select2" value="2">2</option>
<option id="select3" value="3">3</option>
<option id="select4" value="4">4</option>
</select>
<input id="textbox" type="text" value="" />
<div id="selectedValue"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , it works but only in IE ... seems it's not broswer compatible

Comment: I tested it on chrome, firefox and IE it works for me in all three

Comment: use latest jquery library as well